# Responsive editor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, text-editor

My Asp.Net Mvc4 project has twitter bootstrap as front end design. I use FCK editor for content creation purpose. FCK editor behaves awkward in tablet and mobile views. Is there responsive editor which can be put along with twitter bootstrap?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/ . bootstrap-wysihtml5 doesnt have all the features as in FCK editor. It will be hard incorporate all the functionalities of an editor along with responsive design.